# Is there a technical reason C# doesn't have a property setter shorthand similar to object initializer, or is it just a design choice?

Tags: c#, .net, properties, initialization, language-design

If I have an already-created object (e.g. a control on a form) and I want to initialize a number of properties, I have to do this:

```
myObj.Details.Color = Colors.Red;
myObj.Details.Name = "My Object";
myObj.Details.Location = Location.Here;
```

Everyone knows about object initializers, e.g. `var details = new MyObjectDetails() { Color = Colors.Red, Name = "My Object", Location = Location.Here };`, but is there a technical reason that that ability is not provided for existing objects?  E.g.

```
myObj.Details { Color = Colors.Red, Name = "My Object", Location = Location.Here };
```

Edit:

Here's my real-world example.  Third party control (Infragistics UltraWinGrid):

```
_clientTimeDetailUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderAppearance.FontData.Name = gridHeaderCellFont.Name;
_clientTimeDetailUltraGrid.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderAppearance.FontData.SizeInPoints = gridHeaderCellFont.SizeInPoints;
```

Imagine how tedious that gets.

Comment: Just wrangles about syntax and usefulness. See [#2580](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2580), [#1534](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1534), [#803](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/803), [#1825](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1825), and many others besides

Comment: Usefulness?  It would save so much typing.

Comment: That is indeed the opinion of some, as expressed in the issues I linked. I invite you to read them, and the discussions they contain

Comment: Note that C# explicitly does not have the goal of reducing *typing*. The focus is more on easy of understanding, and on maintainability. For your real-world example, a temporary variable will get you a long way without needing language changes

Comment: @canton7 Thank you.  Then this post serves as a sign-post for people wondering the same (none of those came up when I googled, so people googling the terms I did can be directed through here).

Comment: You could put FontData in a local variable.

Comment: "For your real-world example, a temporary variable will get you a long way without needing language changes" @canton7 good point.